# 以下のリポジトリのソースをビルドできない

Tags: python, c++, build

こちらのリポジトリのプログラムをビルドすることができません。

https://github.com/EPFL-LGG/Cshells

必要なライブラリのboostやcholmodやumfpackの機能を持つsuitesparseなどは取得しました。

追記

OSをUbuntu22.4.3 LTSに変更しましたが、依然としてビルドできない状態です。
以下のようなエラーが複数出ました。

```
FAILED: ../ext/elastic_rods/3rdparty/MeshFEM/3rdparty/OffscreenRenderer/python/_offscreen_renderer.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
: && /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-color=auto -O3  -flto -shared  -o ../ext/elastic_rods/3rdparty/MeshFEM/3rdparty/OffscreenRenderer/python/_offscreen_renderer.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so ext/elastic_rods/3rdparty/MeshFEM/3rdparty/OffscreenRenderer/src/python_bindings/CMakeFiles/_offscreen_renderer.dir/offscreen_renderer.cc.o  -Wl,-rpath,/mnt/c/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin  /mnt/c/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin/glew32d.dll  -lopengl32  -lglu32  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so && cd /home/siwameron/python_codes/Cshells/build/ext/elastic_rods/3rdparty/MeshFEM/3rdparty/OffscreenRenderer/src/python_bindings && /usr/bin/strip /home/siwameron/python_codes/Cshells/ext/elastic_rods/3rdparty/MeshFEM/3rdparty/OffscreenRenderer/python/_offscreen_renderer.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopengl32: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglu32: No such file or directory
```

追加で質問なのですが、
https://github.com/EPFL-LGG/Cshells/tree/main/ext/elastic_rods#c-code-dependencies
こちらのGetting Startedの
A few more packages need to be installed on a fresh Ubuntu 19.04 install:
という文章は、インストールしたばかりのライブラリなどは何も入れていない状態のUbuntuにこれらのライブラリを入れればよいということであっていますか。

Comment: リビジョン6で質問内容が全く異なる内容に変わっていて、リビジョン5までに付けた回答が意味不明なものになってしまっています。質問者がやりたいことは変わっていないのでしょうが、リビジョン6は全く異なる質問内容ですので、本質問はリビジョン5に戻してクローズし、リビジョン6は別の質問を立ててください。

Answer (score 1):

以下、[質問リビジョン5](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/98150/5)への回答。

エラーメッセージの通り、combine.cppの94, 95行目で明らかに同じパラメーターでテンプレートをインスタンス化しようとしています。
95行目を削除すれば取り合えずビルドはできるかもしれませんが、作者はWindows環境でビルド確認すらしていないはずなので、Windowsで動くかどうかは怪しいです。

https://github.com/EPFL-LGG/Cshells/blob/main/ext/elastic_rods/3rdparty/libigl/include/igl/combine.cpp

```
#ifdef WIN32
template void igl::combine<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>, Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1>,Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1> >(class std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,class std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > > const &,class std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,class std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > > const &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1> > &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1> > &);
template void igl::combine<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>, Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1>,Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1> >(class std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,class std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > > const &,class std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,class std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > > const &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> > &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1> > &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<unsigned __int64,-1,1,0,-1,1> > &);
#endif
```